# How to create a communication between Java Desktop Application and Web Application PHP?

Tags: java, php

I have 1 web application in PHP and one desktop application in Java on a machine.

I tried to make the connection between the two applications; because I need my web application send a file to my desktop application and this can make trades and returns a result (number) to my website.

The file I'm posting from my web application, I am saving to a shared folder on both applications, so that once the file Java application can read it up.

Is there any way to make the bridge between the two?

Comment: You need use same database for both app. other than that it depends on your requirements.

Comment: You say you write the file into a folder, isn't that the bridge between the two? What is the problem with that approach? What code have you written in an attempt to solve it? In general, I have to say that using a desktop app as a server and a web app as a client is a bad design. Web applications should be the ones that get requests, process them and return results, not the other way around. What if somebody shuts down the desktop computer at the end of the day?

Comment: Your web app needs to provide some kind of service that returns json or XML which the client can call using standard http commands. You could look at using apaches HttpClient API which makes it easier to interact with http

Answer (score 1):

I think that a cool way to design this type of application would be to design the web App as a server app preferably as a web service and then the java App as a client calling the service. Both Apps can exchange data using Xml.  You check-out this link to get started on web services in php http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/671437/Creating-Web-Service-Using-PHP-Within-Minutes